# Extract the value of the <text> attribute to a variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, attributes

```
<svg>
    <text id="t1" x="50" y="50"> text1 </text>
</svg>

<script>
    var t1 = document.getElementById("t1").value;
    alert(t1);
</script>
```

Hello to experts.
I can’t get the value (text1) of the  attribute into a variable (t1).
What methods for this are in javascript? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```js
var t1 = document.getElementById("t1").textContent;
console.log(t1);
```

```html
<svg>
    <text id="t1" x="50" y="50"> text1 </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the .textContent property?